# How to rotate .png rendered from div with canvas 90° ccw?

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, png, html2canvas

Let me start off by saying that I'm new to working with the Canvas element. I've managed to get a div to render as a png with jQuery and html2canvas.js, but I'd like to rotate the png 90 degrees counter-clockwise.

I assume I need to do this in the canvas stage, before the outputting it as a png for it to be *persistent* even when the image is downloaded – how would I go about and accomplish that?

This is what I've got at the moment, which is working (minus the rotation)

```
html2canvas($("#portrait_back_div"), {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
        //document.getElementById('canvas').appendChild(canvas);
        var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

        var image = new Image();
        image.src = data;
        document.getElementById('portrait_back_png').appendChild(image);
        //$( "#portrait_back_div" ).hide();
    }
});
```

I appreciate any help I can get, even though this might seem like a basic question. [This fiddle basically works on the same principles as my project it you want to take a look.](http://jsfiddle.net/lennyekberg/kgx3jxnf/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would have to create a new canvas, then translate to center to move origin to center (here functions as pivot for rotation), rotate then draw image.

Finally extract image from the rotated canvas.

### Example

```js
html2canvas($("#portrait_back_div"), {
  onrendered: function (canvas) {

    // create intermediate canvas
    var rotCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");

    // swap width and height
    rotCanvas.width = canvas.height;
    rotCanvas.height = canvas.width;

    // get context
    var rctx = rotCanvas.getContext("2d");

    // translate to center (rotation pivot)
    rctx.translate(rotCanvas.width * 0.5, rotCanvas.height * 0.5);

    // rotate -90° (CCW)
    rctx.rotate(-Math.PI * 0.5);

    // draw image offset so center of image is on top of pivot
    rctx.drawImage(canvas, -canvas.width * 0.5, -canvas.height * 0.5);

    // extract image from rotate canvas
    var data = rotCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = data;
    document.getElementById('portrait_back_png').appendChild(image);
    //$( "#portrait_back_div" ).hide();
  }
});
```

```js
// proof-of-concept example
var img = new Image;
img.onload = function() {
  var rotCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var rctx = rotCanvas.getContext("2d");
  rotCanvas.width = this.height;
  rotCanvas.height = this.width;
  rctx.translate(rotCanvas.width * 0.5, rotCanvas.height * 0.5);
  rctx.rotate(-Math.PI * 0.5);
  rctx.drawImage(this, -this.width * 0.5, -this.height * 0.5);
  document.body.appendChild(this);
  document.body.appendChild(rotCanvas)
};
img.src = "//i.imgur.com/YqeJUhl.jpg?1";
```

```html
<h4>Original on top, rotated canvas at bottom</h4>
```

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you, that was very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

add at the end of onrendered:

```
image.style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
```

you need more variations of transform to get it working cross browsers

Comment: That will only rotate the image when it is rendered in the browser, not the source material itself – which is what I want to achive.

Comment: oh I understand. was not clear from the question. I think, that you can rotate all elements contained in canvas. can you share the source of the canvas?

Comment: The source is a standard div with text rendered to canvas with html2canvas.